# Trying to make SplashScene (Cocos2d) form the book of Pablo Ruiz, and it doesnt work

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I add this scene to project and run it at ProjectRunDelegate
it fell when method cFadeAndShow starts
Can anybody tell me whats the problem?

im using xCode 3.2.6
and cocos2d 1.0.1

Or maybe someone already has working splash scene to show some company's logos on starts of game

Thanks

```
#import "SplashScene.h"
@implementation SplashScene

-(id) init {
    if ( (self = [super init])) {   
        [self addChild:[SplashLayer node]];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

@implementation SplashLayer

-(id) init {
    if ( (self = [super init])) {

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        NSMutableArray * splashImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i =1; i<=2; i++) {
            CCSprite *splashImage = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"splash%d.png",i]];
            if (splashImage == nil) {
                CCLOG(@"splashImage is nil");
            }
            [splashImage setPosition:ccp(240,160)];
            [self addChild:splashImage];
            if (i!=1) 
                [splashImage setOpacity:0];
                [splashImages addObject:splashImage];
        }
        [self fadeAndShow:splashImages];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) fadeAndShow:(NSMutableArray *) images{   // add the meehods

    if ([images count]<=1) {
        [images release];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[GameScene scene]]; 
    }

    else {

        CCSprite *actual = (CCSprite *)[images objectAtIndex:0];
        [images removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        CCSprite * next = (CCSprite *)[images objectAtIndex:0];

        [actual runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2], [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1],
                           [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(remove:)],nil]];
        [next runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2], [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1],
                         [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2],
                         [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(cFadeAndShow:data:) data:images],nil]];
    }

}
-(void) cFadeAndShow:(id)sender dara:(void*)data{
    NSMutableArray * images = (NSMutableArray *) data;
    [self fadeAndShow:images];
}
-(void)remove:(CCSprite *)s{
    [s.parent removeChild:s cleanup:YES];
}
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: are you using ARC ? And can you add NSLog(@"Images count = %d", [images count]) at the beggining of fadeAndShow method and post it ?

Comment: Arc with Xcode 3? Definitely not. Vlad if you're using these versions to be on the same versions as the book that's ok, but if you plan on actually releasing an app you'll have to upgrade xcode eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [CCTransitionZoomFlipAngular 
    transitionWithDuration:2 
    scene:[GameScene node]
    orientation:kOrientationLeftOver]];
```